# Wipe free space on external SSD

Tags: macos, ssd, secure-erase

I bought an external SSD which is not working fine with my new Macbook Air running under Monterey. I wanted to erase the Disk securely before sending it back but I just noticed that it's not possible to choose the security option during the erase process. I also can't find the option "wipe free space". Is it safe to normally erase the disk and send it back? I tried to encrypt the disk, erase it. re-rencrypt it... But the disk is not working fine and I am not sure if the encryption is working.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you are not sure about the state of the SSD, do a simple risk assessment:

If you send the disk back as is, a) what is the cost (in reputation, commercial, etc.) to you if the data on the disk were to be read and disclosed, and b) how likely do you think that is?

If you don't send the disk back (instead destroy and replace), what is the  replacement cost?

I think you can make that assessment and act accordingly.  This is a decision that always has to be done before returning a faulty disk.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when using another USB-C cable to plug the SSD (I used the cable sent with the macBook for charging), the security level option appears when I try to erase the SSD. It took me more than 10 hours to erase the SSD and now the image recovery software does not find anything on the SSD.

Comment: Which software performed the erase and which software performed the check for recovery?

Comment: Erase with disk utility provided in macOS. I checked with a free tool from the internet, can't remember the name